# Is it possible to groupBy (month) and sum (each column) in table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| date    | type_a | type_b  | type_zzz|
+---------+--------+---------+---------+
|01-01-18 | 12     | 10      |       1 |
|02-01-18 | 2      | 5       |       1 |
|03-01-18 | 7      | 2       |       2 |
|01-02-18 | 13     | 6       |      55 |
|02-02-18 | 22     | 33      |       5 |
+---------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Hi,

In above example, I would like to know if it's possible to groupBy month and sum each column when getting results in Laravel (tables are dynamic so there are no models for them and also some tables don't have column 'type_a' other don't have 'type_zzz' etc...).

What I'm looking to get from above table is something like this:

```
"01" =>
    'type_a' : '21',
    'type_b' : '17',
    'type_zzz': '4'
 "02" => 
     'type_a' : '35',
     'type_b' : '39',
     'type_zzz': '60'
```

I'm using following code to group it by month but I'm not able to find solution to return sum by each column:

```
DB::table($id)->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->repdate)->format('m');;
  });
```

Comment: Is the date actually in the format `d-m-y` in your database, or is it actually in the correct ISO format of `Y-m-d`? Are all values from a single year (2018), or is grouping months from different years what you want? And what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Dates are in correct ISO format `Y-m-d` and values will be from different years. I'm using mysql. Thanks!

Comment: what are you getting so far?

Comment: @moravac, so if the values are from different years, and you're grouping by month, September 2017 and September 2018 data should be combined, based on your description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can either group and sum the values using an SQL query:

```php
$grouped = DB::table('table_name')
    ->selectRaw('
        SUM(type_a) AS type_a,
        SUM(type_b) AS type_b,
        SUM(type_z) AS type_z
    ')
    ->groupByRaw('MONTH(date)')
    ->get();
```

Or if you don't want to have to specify the column names in each query, you can use [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby), [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), and [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) on your collection:

```php
$grouped = DB::table('table_name')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function ($item) {
        return Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('m');
    })
    ->map(function ($group) {
        $group = $group->toArray();
        $summed = [];

        $columns = array_keys($group[0]);
        array_shift($columns);

        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $summed[$column] = array_sum(array_column($group, $column));
        }

        return $summed;
    });
```

Comment: I'm trying second solution but I'm getting following error:

`array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Comment: @moravac - I've edited my answer. Unfortunately I don't have Laravel installed anywhere to be able to test this, so I was writing it from memory.

Comment: No luck, `Call to undefined method stdClass::keys()`

Comment: Okay, back to `array_keys()` and just casting the `group` to an array.

Comment: Getting close, now problem is with `array_column`:

`array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Comment: Lol. Okay, updated again to cast the `group` to an array.

Comment: Now I'm getting results but they are grouped by day and sum is 0:

`Collection {#236 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    "2018/06" => array:25 [▼
      0 => 0
      1 => 0
      2 => 0
      3 => 0
      4 => 0
      5 => 0
      6 => 0
      7 => 0`

Comment: Can you `dd($group, $group->first());` inside the first `map` function?

Comment: Please find ss here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QYI2jlBrFaw5_Wj3-T2hBdFR6XLT9qa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for that. Okay, the latest edit is far more verbose, but I noticed it was necessary to remove the date field from the array. Hopefully this will work this time. If not, I think you'll have to debug yourself, or wait for someone who has Laravel installed to help.

Comment: Thanks man! Small change:

instead of: `$summed[$column] = array_column($group, $column);`

it needs to be: `$summed[$column] =  array_sum(array_column($group, $column));`

Once again, thank you so much!